# How to add custom product on catalog search collection?

Tags: magento-1.7, catalogsearch, search, product-collection

Currently I am trying to add some custom products on CatalogSearch collection . For this I am working on `Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Layer`. I know that its core part of Magento but whenever I 'll get any success on this code I will override `CatalogSearch_Model`.

Rightnow I am working on this method

```
 public function prepareProductCollection($collection)
    {
        $collection
            ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
            ->addSearchFilter(Mage::helper('catalogsearch')->getQuery()->getQueryText())
            ->setStore(Mage::app()->getStore())
            ->addMinimalPrice()
            ->addFinalPrice()
            ->addTaxPercents()
            ->addStoreFilter()
            ->addUrlRewrite();

        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInSearchFilterToCollection($collection);

// my custom code start

$collection2 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array(1,2));

$collectiondata=$collection2->getData();

foreach($collectiondata as $customdata)
{
$collection->addItem($customdata);
}

        return $this;
    }
```

With this code I can able add my custom product into the original collection but It create an Issue on catalog search result. It Means If in search result original product found then it successful works otherwise not.

Any help will be appreciated

Thank you

Comment: Hi, seems hat prepareProductCollection method is not called if there are no search results, did you debug call of method for no results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be because it's an empty collection. Without further testing I wouldn't know for sure. But maybe give this a try

```
public function prepareProductCollection($collection)
{
    $collection
        ->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id')
        ->addSearchFilter(Mage::helper('catalogsearch')->getQuery()->getQueryText())
        ->setStore(Mage::app()->getStore())
        ->addMinimalPrice()
        ->addFinalPrice()
        ->addTaxPercents()
        ->addStoreFilter()
        ->addUrlRewrite();


    $extra_collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                            ->addFieldToSelect('entity_id')
                            ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array(1,2));

    $collection_ids = array_merge($collection->getAllId(), $extra_collection);

    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                            ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
                            ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', $collection_ids);


    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInSearchFilterToCollection($collection);

    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I might be a bit late but hope it helps someone else. I had a similar problem. The results started displaying after I reindexed.